# After Install Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0, installation

I installed `Magento 2.0`, but when I go in `app` folder there is no `code` folder. So is `Magento 2.0` installed properly or not?
Or when I go into `app/design/frontend/Magento/`, there is nothing in this folder.

Can anyone tell me that `magento 2.0` install properly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default Magento doesn't contain code folder inside app/ after installation.**

**Also app/design/frontend/Magento doesn't contains any folder after fresh setup.**

If you made any custom extension in magento at that time you need to create code folder inside app folder and keep your custom extension under this folder.

so no need to scare about your installation, your installation is completed. first you have to check about your frontend and backend, whether its working or not?

Comment: Yes Backend and Frontend is working completely.

Comment: So you have installed magento is correct, please let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you install it.
If you clone the repo from [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2) you will get the code in `app/code`, but if you [downloaded](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download) magento and installed it via composer, all the modules will be in `vendor` folder.
It's ok...if the installer worked, your M2 instance should work.